# Finding email of calendar owner in the response of google calendar API's events.list?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am developing a web app that displays calendar statistics of my co-workers. To display the person's email, I am using a field called 'summary' (Basically the response object does not contain an `id` field. It only has `summary` field.)

In most cases, it is the email of the person. IT WORKS.

BUT in cases when the person has changed the name of the calendar to 'Work' or something, it appears as 'Work' instead of 'cathie@mydomain.com'. In that case I can't know his/her email, hence I cannot print those statistics.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is there a field in the API response of `gapi.client.calendar.events.list` response that has email of the owner of the calendar?
2. Are there any javascript tricks to pass this info (calendarId) into `'request.execute(function(resp)'` and access it from inside the callback function?
3. If there is a standard way of doing this, please suggest.

---

```
function getStatistics() {
    people = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Cathie'];
    people.forEach(fetchStats);
}

function fetchStats(person) {
    var calendarId = person + '@mydomain.com';

    // ... some code

    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': calendarId,
        'timeMax': (new Date()).toISOString(),
        'timeMin': '2016-01-01T00:00:00+05:30'
  });

  request.execute(function(resp) {
        var calendarId = resp.summary;

        if (calendarId.indexOf('@') == -1) {
            window.alert(resp + "\n" + calendarId);
            return;
        }

        // code to render statistics on events of the calendarId
  );
}
```

Comment: have you tried dumping the "request" object to see if it contains your request? The calendarId may be stored there as a public property of the gapi.client.calendar.events.list object.

Comment: @Dexter, that certainly helps. I find the desired email hiding in `request.hg.hg.path`. It's value is 
`/calendar/v3/calendars/cathie%40mydomain.com/events?orderBy=updated&showDeleted=false&singleEvents=true&timeMax=2016-03-17T04%3A24%3A50.598Z&timeMin=2016-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%2B05%3A30`.                                                         - Is it hacky to retrieve this way.                                                                    - I will refer to the documentation to see if `request` has a nice method to get this.            - But this works

Comment: Actually, it might be better to create an array of objects for each of the "people" and assign your requests and responses there. I.

Comment: well, if you can get to your request object from within the callback, you should be able to get to the calendarid variable you set at the top of the fetchStats function instead of creating a local version of it in your execute callback... albeit by value rather than reference, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getStatistics() {
    people = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Cathie'];
    people.forEach(fetchStats);
}

function fetchStats(person) {
    var calendarId = person + '@mydomain.com';

    // ... some code

    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': calendarId,
        'timeMax': (new Date()).toISOString(),
        'timeMin': '2016-01-01T00:00:00+05:30'
    });

  request.execute(function(resp) {
        //use the calendarId variable set above
        if (calendarId.indexOf('@') == -1) {
            window.alert(resp + "\n" + calendarId);
            return;
        }

        // code to render statistics on events of the calendarId
      });
}
```

All you had to do is remove the local setting of calendarId in your callback. the callback can still reference within the scope of your fetchStats function, I just tested it, and it seems to work fine.